# VTK interaction with rotation about arbitrary axis

Tags: 3d, interactive, vtk

This is something I want to do:

I want to use VTK to interact with rotation about arbitrary axis. The vtkRenderWindowInteractor has a LeftButtonPressedEvent() that can almost do the things I want, except that it cannot rotate the 3D object about an arbitrary axis. In stead it only rotates the object about some default axis.

I am wondering is there anyway to interactive with the 3D object rotating about some arbitrary axis?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try any interactor style?